# How to get the absolut position of a touch event?

Tags: android, view, position

I made a Recylerview and added a button to the left bottom of the Element.
Now when I use:

```java
private View.OnTouchListener onWidthClickListener =
      new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
              int x = (int) event.getX();
              Log.d(TAG, "Width: " + x);

          }
          return false;
        }
      };
```

I get the position of the courser but it is absolute to the button and I want it relative to the hole Screen.

Because it is a RecylerView the button has no fixed position relative to Screen, therefor I can't just add or subtract the values of the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()` to get position relative to screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the coordinates relative to the top left corner of the device screen, then use the raw values.

```
int x = (int)event.getRawX();
int y = (int)event.getRawY();
```

**Exaplain:**

**`getX()`** and **`getY()`**--> return you coordinates relative to the View .

**`MotionEvent.getRawX()`** and **`MotionEvent.getRawY()`** -->return absolute coordinates,regarding the screen of the device.

For more details:[doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent)